# GAE - JDO Query fails while using Enum field and 'contains' operator to filter data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, contains

I am using an Enum field in Datastore entity class.

```
public enum MyEnum{
  A(0x9001L),
  B(0x9002L),
  C(0x9003L),
  D(0x9004L),
  private long value;
  private MyEnum(long value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
};
```

ENTITY

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Log implements Serializable, Comparable<Object>, Cacheable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private MyEnum myEnumVariable;  
}
```

When I make a query by filtering only one Enum type

```
declareParams.append(",Long myEnumVariable");
filterQuery.append(" this.myEnumVariable == myEnumVariable");
```

.. then the code works fine.

But when I make a query to filter multiple Enums

```
declareParams.append(",List myEnumList");
filterQuery.append(" myEnumList.contains(this.myEnumVariable )");
```

I get an error saying -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MyEnum : com.xxx.xxx.MyEnum  is
>   not a supported property type.    at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:149)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.(Query.java:619)
>     at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.addFilter(Query.java:261)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addLeftPrimaryExpression(DatastoreQuery.java:1343)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addExpression(DatastoreQuery.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addExpression(DatastoreQuery.java:1054)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addExpression(DatastoreQuery.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.addFilters(DatastoreQuery.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery.performExecute(DatastoreQuery.java:238)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:92)
>     at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1489)
>     at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1398)
>     at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithMap(JDOQuery.java:334)

NOTE: the object 'myEnumList' is a collection of 'MyEnum' type elements.
When I use a list of 'Long' type elements, I don't see the error, but empty results are returned

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can solve it by quoting, like

```
filterQuery.append(" this.myEnumVariable == 'myEnumVariable'");
```

It's working for me that way.